# Generalizations of the Hairy Ball Theorem to wider classes of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

In 2 dimensions the hairy ball theorem generalizes from spheres to all orientable closed manifolds with nonzero Euler characteristic.

The hairy ball theorem holds for all even dimensional hyperspheres.
Can this be generalized to broader classes of manifolds for higher dimensions?

Comment: The Lefschetz fixed point theorem explains a vast generalization. Check out the details here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @Danu I have only seen the Lefschetz fixed point theorem used to prove HBT for even dimensional hyperspheres. I am after generelizations from hyperspheres in higher dimesions. I have updated the question to reflect this. Does the Lefschetz do this as well?

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing:  there are spheres of arbitrarily large dimensions, and the Lefschetz FPT generalizes the Euler characteristic to intersection numbers with non-identity maps (and still works in any dimension) so it's a very large generalization. Also, who is Danu, it seems I'm the only responder so far.

Comment: @AdamHughes What is the class of manifolds that Lefschetz FPT shows cannot have a continuous non-vanishing vector field? Connecting the dots on this is a little above my level.

Comment: @AdamHughes Sorry I was having 2 discussions simultaneously & I got my wires crossed. Danu was answering one of my other questions

Comment: It seems that the existence/nonexistence of a nonvanishing vector fields is measured in general by the Euler class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class

Comment: @Daniel Mahler, in case you are not aware of this, your first sentence generalizes to any dimension: Any closed manifold with nonzero Euler characteristic has no smooth nonvanishing vector field. This is a consequence of the Poincare-Hopf theorem, which is in turn a consequence of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, as mentioned by other commenters.

Comment: @PhillipAndreae I was not aware of that. I did not realize Euler characteristic was defined for >2 dimensions. It is rarely presented that way.